# Accordion Arrows positioning inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wanting to make arrows for my accordion so they can float to the right but I am having some issues with making it successful.

Here is the small snippet that I'm using to align and define the arrows but they don't seem to be working correctly. I would appreciate all input on this since I've been messing with the formatting for some time now and can't figure it out.

Code being applied:

```
.panel-heading:after {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\e114";
    float: right;
    color: grey;
}
.panel-heading:after {
    content: "\e080";
}
```

Picture for reference:
[image]

How I would like to make it:
[image]

Here is what I currently have:

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cloud.typography.com/7088154/7564812/css/fonts.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style>
/* --- */
@media (max-width: 1023px) {
 .row .row {
  margin-left: -1.0rem;
  margin-right: -1.0rem;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-7 {
        width: 58.334%;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 411px) {
 p {
  font-size: smaller;
 }
 .heading > .col-xs-9 > h4 {
  font-size: small!important;
 }
 .col-xs-2 {
  display: none;
 }
 .col-xs-10 {
  width: 100%;
 }
 .col-xs-4 > span {
  font-size: smaller!important;
 }
 .col-xs-3 > span {
  font-size: inherit;
 }
}
#bannerWrapper {
    display: none;
}
#sticky {
 z-index: 100;
 top: 0;
 position: sticky;
 position : -webkit-sticky;
}
.second {
 background: white;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #5E6A71;
}
#pageTitle {
 display: none;
}
#columnMiddle {
 padding-top: 50px;
}
.heading {
    background-color: #A2AD00;
    display: flex;
}
.sub-heading {
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}


.container {
    /* box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(77,72,69,0.2), 0 6px 10px rgba(77,72,69,0.15); */
    border: 1px solid #5E6A71;
}


/* Change the padding on rows.*/
.container > .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4 {
    padding-top: .6rem!important;
    padding-bottom: .6rem!important;
}
.container > .col-md-5, .col-md-7 {
    padding-top: .2rem!important;
    padding-bottom: .2rem!important;
    font-family: "Whitney A", "Whitney B";
    font-size: large;
}
.col-xs-10, .col-xs-2 {
 padding-top: .2rem!important;
    padding-bottom: .2rem!important;
    font-family: "Whitney A", "Whitney B";
 font-size: medium;
}
.col-xs-10 > span {
    font-size: 18px!important;
}
.col-xs-2 > span {
    font-size: 18px!important;
}
/* ----- */

.even-row > .col-xs-3 {
 padding-top: 10px;
}
.odd-row > .col-xs-3 {
 padding-top: 10px;
}


.col-xs-3 {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #A2AD00;
    font-family: "Archer SSm A", "Archer SSm B"!important;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.col-xs-3 > span {
    font-size: 15px!important;
    font-family: "Archer SSm A", "Archer SSm B";
    font-weight: 800;
}

/* Junior/Mid/Senior Sub-Headings */
.col-xs-4 > span {
 font-family: "Archer SSm A", "Archer SSm B"!important;
 font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #231f20;
}
.col-xs-4 > ul > li {
    font-family: "Archer SSm A", "Archer SSm B";
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #231f20;
}
/* ----- */

.col-xs-9 {
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 border-left: 1px solid #5E6A71;
}
.col-xs-9 > p {
    font-size: 13px!important;
    font-family: "Archer SSm A", "Archer SSm B";
    font-weight: 800;
}
#sub {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: smaller;
}

/* Heading */
.heading > .col-xs-9 {
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 font-family: "Archer SSm A", "Archer SSm B"!important;
 font-size: small;
    border-left: 0px!important;
}
.heading > .col-xs-9 > h4 {
 font-size: x-large;
 color: white!important;
 font-family: "Whitney A", "Whitney B";
 margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.heading > .col-xs-3 {
 padding-right: 7px!important;
 padding-left: 7px!important;
 align-self: center;
}
/* ----- */

/* Change background color on even rows: Client Service and Counsel, 
Strategic and Creative Integrated Programming, etc.. */
.even-row {
 background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

/* Change background color on odd rows: Account Management and Operational Excellence, 
Recruitment and Retention, etc.. */
.odd-row {
 background-color: #F8F8F8;
}

/* Change background color of left-hand headings: Client, Talent, etc.. */
.left-hand-header-background {
 background-color: #EEAF00;
    font-family: "Whitney A", "Whitney B";
}
.left-hand-header-background > span {
    font-family: "Whitney A", "Whitney B"!important;
}

/* Change background color of right-hand headings: Client, Talent, etc.. */
.right-hand-header-background {
 background-color: #A2AD00;
}

.bl {
    border-left: 1px solid lightgray;
}
.bb {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5E6A71;
}
.bg-white {
    background-color: white;
}



/* Sections */
.mainText {
    font-style: italic;
    color: #00C6D7;
}
#section {
    border-top: 1px solid #5E6A71;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5E6A71;
}
#section1, #section2, #section3, #section4 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5E6A71;
}
/* ----- */



.title {
    color: #A2AD00;
    font-family: "Whitney A", "Whitney B";
    font-size: larger;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.panel-heading {
 padding: 0px!important;
 border-left-width: 0px;
 border-top-width: 0px;
 border-right-width: 0px;
 border-bottom-width: 0px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.panel-heading:after {
    /* symbol for "opening" panels */
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';  /* essential for enabling glyphicon */
    content: "\e114";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
    float: right;        /* adjust as needed */
    color: grey;         /* adjust as needed */
}
.panel-heading:after {
    /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
    content: "\e080";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
}

/* Slick Carousel */
.slick-next {
    right: 10px!important;
}
.slick-prev:before {
  color: #5E6A71!important;
}
.slick-next:before {
  color: #5E6A71!important;
}
.no-arrows > .slick-next,
.no-arrows > .slick-prev {
   display: none!important;
}
/* ----- */

/* BootStrap 4 Classes */
.py-5 {
    padding-bottom: 3rem!important;
    padding-top: 3rem!important;
}
.py-2 {
    padding-bottom: .5rem!important;
    padding-top: .5rem!important;
}
.text-white {
    color: #fff!important;
}
.text-left {
    text-align: left!important;
}
.text-uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase!important;
}
.font-weight-bold {
    font-weight: 700!important;
}
.row-11 {
    height: auto!important;
}
.container > ul {
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.img-responsive {
 display: inline-block;
}
/* ----- */
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
 <div class="accordion-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="row bb panel-heading" id="section1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#section" data-target="#collapseOne" href="#collapseOne">
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-5 left-hand-header-background">
            <span class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">Client</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-7 right-hand-header-background">
         <span><br/></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    
 <div class="panel-collapse collapse s1" id="collapseOne">
    <div class="row bb even-row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <span>Client Service and Counsel</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <section class="regular slider no-arrows">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <ul>
                     <li>Demonstrates good judgement and ability to solve problems</li>
                     <li>Demonstrates ability to clearly articulate concepts and ideas</li>
                        <li>Develops understanding of clients' business and goals</li>
                        <li>Beings to understand agency's solutions for clients and how they drive business results</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <ul>
                     <li>Develops annual or campaign-based plans for client needs</li>
                     <li>Proactively provides recommendations to maximize results and minimize challenges</li>
                     <li>Demonstrates strong presentation skills, ability to articulate and sell ideas effectively to clients and colleagues</li>
                        <li>Understands clients' business needs and contributes to building strong client relationships</li>
                        <li>Develops programs and solutions that effectively meet business needs and priorities</li>
                        <li>Demontrates a good understanding of the client's industry, competitors and trends</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <ul>
                     <li>Serves as primary point of contact for high level issues, concerns and requests</li>
                     <li>Leads and manages client programs within budget parameters</li>
                     <li>Leads presentations, ability to persuade and sell concepts, ideas, and stories in both large gatherings and one on one</li>
                        <li>Anticipates clients' business and communications needs</li>
                        <li>Is responsive, results-oriented and growth-focused</li>
                        <li>Counsels clients on capabilities, products and services that will deliver greatest value to their business</li>
                        <li>Is able to have tough client conversations</li>
                        <li>Inspires clients' confidence in agency and account team</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row bb odd-row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <span>Account Management and Operational Excellence</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <section class="regular slider no-arrows">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <ul>
                     <li>Produces documents or assets for clients with guidance</li>
                        <li>Activitely contibutes to teams</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <ul>
                     <li>Ensures teams are meeting client deadlines and objectives</li>
                     <li>Leads planning meetings and brainstorms to support client needs and requests</li>
                        <li>Collaborates effectively with colleagues and clients</li>
                        <li>Relies on lessons learned to lead successful program execution</li>
                        <li>Keeps account leadership informed of client successes and challenges</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Develops and drives integrated strategies, including clear objectives and metrics</li>
                        <li>Leads globally and uses all resources to deliver seamless integrated solutions</li>
                        <li>Ensures successful execution of programs and leads post-program analysis to drive continued learning and improvement</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row even-row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <span>Strategic and Creative Integrated Programming</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <section class="regular slider no-arrows">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <ul>
                     <li>Contributes to project or campaign plans</li>
                        <li>Proactively contributes ideas</li>
                        <li>Participates in brainstorms and/or other creative processes</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Brings new ideas to the team</li>
                        <li>Inspires colleagues to use creative sources and resources</li>
                        <li>Is able to communicate the business values of recommended solutions</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Regularly brings clients new ideas and creative solutions</li>
                        <li>Anticipates how potential ideas and solutions may play out when executed</li>
                        <li>Drives business growth through new tools, products and ideas</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    

    <div class="row panel-heading" id="section2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#section" data-target="#collapseTwo" href="#collapseTwo">
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-5 left-hand-header-background">
            <span class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">Talent</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-7 right-hand-header-background">
         <span><br/></span>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="panel-collapse collapse s2" id="collapseTwo">
    <div class="row bb odd-row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <span>Recruitment and Retention</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <section class="regular slider no-arrows">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Recommends the agency to prospective employees</li>
                        <li>Identifies talented candidates and communicates them to hiring teams</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Assists with recruitment, staffing and performance management</li>
                        <li>Is committed to diverse and inclusive hiring, teams and perspective</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <ul>
                     <li>Participates in hiring process, including recruiting, interviews and selection</li>
                     <li>Guides, builds and manages teams for practice areas</li>
                        <li>Ensures we have the right people in place to drive our growth</li>
                        <li>Attracts, grows and retains talent</li>
                        <li>Demonstrates commitment to diverse and inclusive hiring, teams and perspective</li>
                        <li>Is adept at providing effective performance feedback and coaching</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row bb even-row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <span>Professional Development</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <section class="regular slider no-arrows">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <ul>
                     <li>Keeps supervisor and account teams informed of work status and product</li>
                     <li>Demonstrates positive, team-focused attitude</li>
                        <li>Builds relationships with colleagues within and across teams, practices, offices</li>
                        <li>Seeks and embraces feedback</li>
                        <li>Collaborates well</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <ul>
                     <li>Contributes to professional development of team members and colleagues</li>
                     <li>Supervises team members and oversee their work on client accounts</li>
                        <li>Serves as a role model to junior staff</li>
                        <li>Mentors direct reports</li>
                        <li>Is able to provide effective feedback to team leaders, colleagues and direct reports</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <ul>
                     <li>Recommends promotion nominations and provides input on compensation, recognition and professional development</li>
                        <li>Ensures performance evaluations are completed on time</li>
                        <li>Influences and inspires others to do their best work</li>
                        <li>Effectively guides, coaches and develops colleagues at all levels</li>
                        <li>Fosters team collaboration</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row odd-row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <span>Leadership Presence</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <section class="regular slider no-arrows">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Demonstrates passion for learning and openness to coaching</li>
                        <li>Seeks a wide range of assignments</li>
                        <li>Uses agency's learning and development tools</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <ul>
                     <li>Begins to build supervisory skills</li>
                        <li>Relates well with colleagues and clients at all levels</li>
                        <li>Demonstrates professionalism and confidence</li>
                        <li>Takes responsibility for own development and seeks opportunities to grow</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Shows passion for the agency and commitment to achieving our strategic priorities</li>
                        <li>Demonstrates a global, inclusive and diverse perspective</li>
                        <li>Partners successfully with other colleagues, regions and agencies</li>
                        <li>Is seen as a role model and positive example of bringing the FH culture to life</li>
                        <li>Contributes to thought leadership</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.SPServices"></script> -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".regular").slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: false,
        /* mobileFirst:true, */
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        asNavFor: '.slider',
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 700,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                }
            }]
        });
        $('#section1').on('click', function(e) {
      $(".slick-slider").slick("refresh");
      $('#collapseTwo').collapse('hide');
      $('#collapseThree').collapse('hide');
   $('#collapseFour').collapse('hide');
  });
  $('#section2').on('click', function(e) {
      $(".slick-slider").slick("refresh");
      $('#collapseOne').collapse('hide');
      $('#collapseTwo').collapse('hide');
   $('#collapseThree').collapse('hide');
  });
  $('#section3').on('click', function(e) {
      $(".slick-slider").slick("refresh");
      $('#collapseOne').collapse('hide');
      $('#collapseTwo').collapse('hide');
   $('#collapseFour').collapse('hide');
  });
        $('#section4').on('click', function(e) {
      $(".slick-slider").slick("refresh");
      $('#collapseOne').collapse('hide');
      $('#collapseTwo').collapse('hide');
   $('#collapseThree').collapse('hide');
  });
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *quite* sure I understand exactly what you want, but try adding "position: relative;" to .panel-heading, and instead of "float: right" in your :after, try "position: absolute; right: 0;" ... play around with the right and top positioning til you get it to where you want

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Replace those rules with these:

```
.right-hand-header-background:after {
    /* symbol for "opening" panels */
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';  /* essential for enabling glyphicon */
    font-size: 18px; /* match the font size in the left column*/
    content: "\e114";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
    float: right;        /* adjust as needed */
    color: grey;         /* adjust as needed */
}
.right-hand-header-background:after {
    /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
    content: "\e080";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
    font-size: 18px; /* match the font size in the left column*/
}
```

Also, remove the `<br />` in the right-hand-headers

The :after selector adds the glyph *after the content* of an element, not after the element itself. This included the span and line break, which gave it that odd position. Best.

Edit for response:

So, to get those arrows to change, we need to make new style rules for the collapsed and expanded states, and also add extra javascript to give it that behavior.

check out this pastebin (SO code gadget isnt working out for me)
[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/rEa14TuX)

When you get this solid, you may want to consider assigning a variable for each jQuery selector, like so:

```
let $myRef = $('some selector')
```

This saves the browser having to look it up every time, and makes your code easier to work with.

Comment: This is wonderful Thomas! Removing the <span> and <br> which I used to fill in the space to match the left column fixed the issue. All that I'm experiencing now is that on collapsed, the arrows don't change.

I tried using '.right-hand-header-background.collapsed:after {' but it made no difference.